# Why does my iPhone's directories not start with a "/"?

Tags: iphone, command-line, filesystem, files

I am trying to move some files from one directory of my phone to another using my computer. However, it says I only have read permissions. I know how to get permission using the terminal (i'm using Ubuntu) but for that i'll need to know the name of the file from the root directory all the way to that specific file, or at least go to the directory that file is in (using cd).

However, when I hover my mouse over the directory (folder, if you like), it showed a bunch of text that didn't start with a "/", which is the thing directories are supposed to start with. I tried going there anyways but it didn't work. Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this? Thanks!

btw here's an image of what is happening[image]

Comment: I believe this is more appropriate for another stack, eg. ask ubuntu

Comment: Please flag for mod attention if you don‘t get useful answers here and want us to migrate it to AskUbuntu.

Comment: Having said that: what exactly do you want to transfer on the iPhone? Are you sure the target app is able to access the new files afterwards?

Comment: Also, your question mentions permission issues, your screenshot shows something else. AFAIK gphoto can only access pictures stored on the phone, what are you trying to access here?

Answer (score 1):

They do start with a `/` if you ssh into your device. This requires jailbreaking it currently.

What you're seeing is a product of the way your OS has mounted what's visible to it.